# TypeScript: Can I infer number index value type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a helper function to convert an object of numbered keys to a Map:

```js
interface IndexedObject {
    [index: number]: unknown;
};

const objectToIndexedMap = (indexedObject: IndexedObject) => new Map(
    Object.entries(indexedObject).map(
        ([ index, field ]) => [ Number(index), field ]
    )
);
```

I use it to convert objects I'm getting from the API to a more convenient Map, where I don't need to deal with string keys anymore. The problem is that the returned type is `Map<number, any>`, while I'd like to use the type of those values in `IndexedObject`.

Is it possible to get that type and make my function return this specific type for Map values?

So for example this would throw an error:

```js
interface IndexedNumbers {
    [index: number]: number;
}

const indexedNumbers: IndexedNumbers = api.numbers; // pseudocode
const map = objectToIndexedMap(indexedNumbers);
const foo = map.get(0)!.toUpperCase(); // This should throw an error
```

Of course I know I can hard-type it:

```js
const map: Map<number, number> = objectToIndexedMap(indexedNumbers);
```

But I'd love TypeScript to do that for me. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `IndexedObject[number]` to get `unknown` if that's what you want

Comment: @Bergi `unknown` is temporary. I'm not sure if I should use a generic type or not.

Comment: @Peppermintology they can be both. I'm aware that whenever they are something more complex I should type it myself. But a lot of them are simple numbers, strings etc.

Comment: @Bergi would you be able to help with that one? Perhaps using `IndexedObject[number]` would work, but I don't know how to use it in this case.